# Add dimension to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame that includes a pipe-separated string in one of the fields. I've split this into a list inside an `apply` and added it to the DataFrame. The number and content of the values in the pipe-separated string vary.

```
df = DataFrame([{'wibble': 'a', 'pipestring': 'aa|aaa|aaa'}, 
    {'wibble': 'b', 'pipestring': 'bb|bbbb|bbb|bbbbbb'}])

df['pipelist'] = df['pipestring'].map(lambda x: x.split('|'))
```

I'm pretty new to pandas so could be completely wrong about this, but I think this would be better represented via a DataFrame with multiple index levels so I can take advantage of panda's indexing and other (fabulous) tools. However I can't figure out how to do this. Any pointers / advice on what I should be doing instead much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your computational goal more specifically?

Here's a way to split your data up and create a combined frame

```
In [44]: x = df['pipestring'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.split('|')))

In [45]: x
Out[45]: 
    0     1    2       3
0  aa   aaa  aaa     NaN
1  bb  bbbb  bbb  bbbbbb

In [46]: df.join(x).set_index(['wibble'])
Out[46]: 
                pipestring                 pipelist   0     1    2       3
wibble                                                                    
a               aa|aaa|aaa           [aa, aaa, aaa]  aa   aaa  aaa     NaN
b       bb|bbbb|bbb|bbbbbb  [bb, bbbb, bbb, bbbbbb]  bb  bbbb  bbb  bbbbbb
```

Comment: Thanks - this is exactly what I was trying to do. The only issue I had (again, please forgive my ignorance) is that I had to convert the Series of Series to a list and back again to get pandas to format things as in your output (otherwise I got a DataFrame of Series) `x = DataFrame(list(df['pipestring'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.split('|')))))` Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to get started with that is to `stack` your dataframe:

```
In [44]: df = df.stack()

In [45]: df.ix[0, 'pipelist']
Out[45]: ['aa', 'aaa', 'aaa']

In [46]: df
Out[46]: 
0  pipestring                 aa|aaa|aaa
   wibble                              a
   pipelist               [aa, aaa, aaa]
1  pipestring         bb|bbbb|bbb|bbbbbb
   wibble                              b
   pipelist      [bb, bbbb, bbb, bbbbbb]
```

Does that get you where you want to be?

Comment: Sorry, I obviously didn't explain myself very clearly. I'm trying to add additional columns to my DataFrame (determined by the list I get from converting `pipestring`), not restructure the DataFrame. (Basically as in @Jeff's answer.)